# Why won't this font come out in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, hebrew

I installed this font

http://www.bibleplaces.com/paleo_hebrew_fonts/

http://www.bibleplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/PaleoHebrew.zip

I installed it

It works in Ms Word, this is where it is and what it looks like / should look like. (And this is when in my taskbar it's set to EN - english - rather than hebrew). (If set to hebrew I get the standard hebrew script which is blocky, not paleo hebrew which is stick like). So setting the language bar to EN in the taskbar is correct.

[image]

But when I try it in visual studio, with a textbox I can't get the font to display

I can set the textbox to Wingdings so I know the code for setting the font is correct.

```
   TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();

   string fontname = "Wingdings";  // works
   fontname = "PaleoHebrew";  // doesn't work
   fontname = "Paleo-Hebrew"; // doesn't work
   fontname = "Paleo Hebrew Regular";  // doesn't work

   tb1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontname, 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

The TTF file is PaleoHebrew.TTF, the fonts window shows it as "Paleo Hebrew Regular"

The textbox just displays english

[image]

or if I set the language to (HE) in the taskbar then I get the regular hebrew script, rather than paleo hebrew script. Though that happens in word too. So maybe that's normal.

[image]

I  can't get the textbox in the winforms application written in C# in visual studio C#, display the stick like characters of the paleo hebrew font, though MS  word can display them no problem.

I tried

`System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular`

instead of

`System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold`

But it's still not working.

Comment: Have you restarted VS after installing the font?

Comment: Have you tried font name of `Paleo Hebrew`? Doesn't look like it here.

Comment: Maybe you can use a FontDialog to choose it and then check the correct name.

Comment: It's almost certainly just called [`Paleo Hebrew`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5iIij.png)

Comment: @Gusman yeah that worked.. I restarted visual studio but still had the wrong font name. I tried using a FontDialog and `Messagebos.Show(fd.Font.Name)`  and indeed it was "Paleo Hebrew".  I had wondered at one point how to get visual studio to list font names, but that found the font name.  You can post that as an answer. I like that FontDialog solution

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. Your comment got it first, but gusman's comment was better because it showed me how to find the font name